# The EM field action for interaction with particles

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, integration, action

The action for an EM field that interacts with a set of point particles is

$$
S_{mf} = -\sum_i \frac{e_i}{c} \intop A_k dx^k \tag{27.3}
$$

(ref - Landau & Lifshitz, eq. 27.3.)

In the book mentioned it is said that

> "In each term of this sum. $A_k$ is the potential of the field at that point of spacetime at whih the corresponding particle is located".

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this statement. The integral is over $A_k$, does it mean that each integral is made over a constant value of $A_k$? But since the integral is taken over the entire space, neither of them will converge (unless their value is 0). Or is it the same integral for every particle so we can write

$$
S_{mf} = -C \sum_i \frac{e_i}{c}
$$ 
for $ C =  \intop A_k dx^k$?

Comment: It's analogous to work as $W = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$. Here, $\mathbf{F}$ is the force at the point $\mathbf{x}(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you may be confused by the short-hand being used. In English, "$A_k$  is the potential of the field at that point of spacetime at which the corresponding particle is located". In mathematics,
$$A_k\equiv A_k(x_i(\tau)),~~~~~~~~~~k=0,1,2,3.\tag{1}$$
where $x_i(\tau)$ is the spacetime trajectory of the $i^\text{th}$ particle. In (1), it is now extremely clear that there is only one vector potential, $A$.

The integrals are then the standard integrals which pair a trajectory $x_i(\tau)$ (i.e. a 1-dimensional submanifold of the spacetime $M$) with this fixed 1-form $A\in \Omega^1(M)$ (in vector calculus, this is called the **line integral** of a vector field):
$$S=\sum_{\text{particles}~i}\,\,\int_{i^\text{th}~\text{trajectory }}A\cdot dl$$
Again, note that the *same* background vector potential appears in each line integral! To see how this matches with your expression, note that, for  the trajectory of the $i^\text{th}$ particle $A\cdot dl = A_kdx^k$.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, The $i$th summand in the interaction term (27.3) is a 1-dimensional contour integral over the $i$th particle worldline. It is e.g. not a 4-dimensional integral over the entire spacetime.